# Wine can't find DLLs

Tags: wine, shared-library

The problem that I currently have with my wine installation is that it doesn't find the DLLs to start the game, he says something like:

```
0100:err:module:import_dll Library D3DCOMPILER_43.dll (which is needed by L"B:\\Games\\Game.exe") not found
```

but I know that the DLLs are in the `wineprefix`, only thing is that the DLLs are all lowercase and it seems to work if I symlink the mixcase names to the lowercase names. The weird thing on this is, that prior of knowing it was a case sensitivity problem I just rebooted my system a few times, sometimes it works and the case sensitivity isn't a problem, sometimes it doesn't and says again that he can't find the DLLs. Also it was not always like this, but I don't know since when it started to act like this (but could be since I did set up my system again because of a mistake)

I do setup now a filesystem with case insensitivity introduced with linux kernel version 5.2 but I would like to know whether you can fix this in a normal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with an NTFS drive that I shared with Windows while switching the boats from Windows to Linux for gaming.

The FAQ of proton mentions [read issues with NTFS](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton/wiki/Using-a-NTFS-disk-with-Linux-and-Windows#turning-off-case-sensitivity-in-file-names).

After moving the games that didn't launch to an ext4 partition the issue was gone.

*(Tested with one game left on NTFS and one on ext4. They both had this issue, depending on reboot.
I reproduced the issue with rebooting and testing the game on NTFS. When that game doesn't launch I started the game on ext4. It launched 100% of each of the 6 tries in two reboots where the issue occured.
After another reboot I had the issue with the game on the NTFS drive. After moving that game to ext4 it launched, even without the need of a reboot)*

The FAQ proposes a slightly different fix, by using `lowntfs` which I did not prefer.

Comment: Didn't expect to get a satisfying answer after all this time, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Wine is **case-insensitive** in terms of opening files including DLLs.

With a 99.99% confidence I can say that you don't have this library installed or it's not where Wine expects to find it.

Please use `winetricks` to enable it - it usually works flawlessly. AFAIK Ubuntu and its derivatives come with this package but still I'd highly recommend downloading it straight from GIT: https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks

> I do setup now a filesystem with case insensitivity introduced with linux kernel version 5.2 but I would like to know whether you can fix this in a normal way.

Wine has never required this feature and it uses its own file open routines to open files. You're trying to solve the issue which is not related to Wine.

---

Purge your wineprefix (`$HOME/.wine`) or create a new one ( `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine123" wine app.exe` ). I believe the issue is down to something on your side. When you keep messing with your default wine prefix sometimes things go awry - for that matter it's recommended to have separate prefixes for separate applications to eliminate any possible issues.

Comment: I already have the packages installed with winetricks, exactly this is the weird thing, sometimes it works and in another system boot it doesn't work and if I do create symlinks with the exact case he expects it does somehow always work, but this isn't clean enough and too much work to create symlinks for every dll

Comment: Already done this a few times, the only thing that I currently know that fixes it are a few system reboots (which then only lasts for this system boot) or a case insensitive filesystem (what I currently do try out)

Edit: Someone asked to purge the wineprefix

Comment: Again, never heard of this issue before. If you can **reproduce it reliably** with a **fresh wine prefix**, please file a bug report at https://bugs.winehq.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Wine

Comment: Wasn't sure whether this is a bug or wrong configuration of my system from my side, but seems like I should report this

Comment: Again, report it **only if you can reliably reproduce it**. Unreproducible bug reports only waste developers time. So far from what I've heard you cannot quite describe how you arrive at this situation, so I'm not sure you're doing everything correctly.

Comment: Thing is, I can't reliable reproduce it, I don't know either why it should depend on my system boot and be solved sometimes with a different system boot, it was also not always the case, it started a few months ago, I would also probably do a new system setup to check whether then the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in wine, so not sure what is the 'normal' way for such problems.
But the 'traditional' way is to just create a link (sym or hard) to the file with a different name.

```
cd /opt/wine-stable/lib/wine/
ln -s d3dcompiler_43.dll D3DCOMPILER_43.dll
```

Definitely not an ideal solution, but as a quick and dirty fix it usually works.

Comment: Thanks, but as written in the question this is already my current workaround and I do not always know in which case each letter has to be written because not every program does print the error (probably because of starting child processes which don't share the same stdout)